# Why did Nun say, "Well...Yes, I know"?

Tags: dialogue, the-two-popes

In biographical drama movie *The Two Popes* (2019), Nun offers Pope Francis a dish to eat:

> Nun: A typical Bavarian dish, Knödel mit Soße. **Well...Yes, I know**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the line does not appear in the [**script**](https://pmcdeadline2.files.wordpress.com/2019/12/the-two-popes-ampas-script.pdf), it does offer some insight.

Basically, she's aware that the dish is unappetising and is sympathising with Francis for having to eat it.

> ```
> A covered plate is placed before Bergoglio.
>
>     NUN: (CONT'D)
>   He just prefers it that way. But he has arranged for you both to eat 
>   the same meal. It’s a traditional Bavarian dish. A favorite. Just as
>   his Mother used to make it.
>
>   She takes the lid off the plate. Underneath is a profoundly
>   unappetizing Bavarian soup with noodles. Bergoglio reacts.
>
>    NUN:
>    Knoedel mit sosse.
>
>
>   There’s a lot of sympathy in just saying the name. Bergoglio laughs. 
>   The nun joins in.
> ```